# Lightbox type of photo gallery on an externally hosted site/CSM

Tags: jquery, cross-domain, lightbox, lightbox2, cross-site

Its more 3 years since I wrote any code, hence pardon me if this looks silly.  I am allowed to post content on an externally hosted site (say http://www.example.com) that I do not control.  My content can be in HTML, CSS and JS. I have a bunch of photos in dropbox that I wish to load in my content page (http://www.example.com/MyContentPage). This page uses jQuery (I checked it).

I  have my images in dropbox and load them in a list, but as the number of images are increasing, I wish to load them as a gallery.  But I do not control the root folder and the relative paths.  Hence any JS/CSS/Image that I need should be hosted in Dropbox or from a different domain (which needs to be referenced in my CMS page)

When I was looking at lightbox (https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/), I see that it comes with all the necessary folders, but since I cannot "install" lightbox2, am wondering if there is an easier way for me to do a photogallery with lightbox (or something similar). I am thinking that changing the relative paths for css and images in lightbox2 may work, but I don't know. Would greatly appreciate any ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: There should be no problem in simply hosting the lightbox code on another site and using absolute paths to call those files from those on example.com. Alternatively you could use cdnjs which hosts all the lightbox2 files for you: http://cdnjs.com/libraries/lightbox2 Or is this not the question?

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need to “install” the script – just pointing to the JS and CSS resources located elsewhere on the net should suffice. You could even place them in your DropBox account and reference them from there (assuming DropBox does not prevent this in any way, but since they seem to have nothing against being used to host the images, why should they object when you do the same with some JS/CSS files).

The other option would be to look for a dedicated CDN that hosts those files for you – for common scripts there are a couple of services that do that already … whether or not there’s one hosting this specific script, you’d have to research. (What you should not do though, is link to the files directly on github – they explicitly do not want to be used as a CDN for such cases.)

Answer (score 0):

In your html file put the following (all hosted on a CDN) in the head:

```
<!-- Magnific Popup core CSS file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/0.9.9/magnific-popup.css"> 

<!-- jQuery 1.7.2+ or Zepto.js 1.0+ ===> Optional if your site has jQuery already but 
Check what version of jQuery your example.com site has-->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.11/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<!-- Magnific Popup core JS file -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/0.9.9/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.gallery').magnificPopup({
type:'image',
gallery:{
enabled:true
}
});
});
</script>
```

This is the html for your images:

```
<div class="gallery">
<a href="path-to-image.jpg">Open image 1 (gallery #1)</a><!-- can be absolute path -->
<a href="path-to-image.jpg">Open image 2 (gallery #1)</a>
<!-- more links  -->
</div>
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/mm26cox1/)

You could also host the css and js from your dropbox. You just need to enter the link.
For more info on Magnific-Popup:
[Magnific-Popup Docs](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html)

Answer (score 0):

I like to use Featherlight (http://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/)

There is also a gallery option, but it allows you to pull your data sources from an outisde source such as a CDN. Plus it's very small so that you can keep your website optimized.